# resample dataframe and divide values over new sample frequency

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, resample

How do I upsample a dataframe using resample() to get the initial values divided over the new sample frequency?

Dataframe with monthly sample frequency

```
                       date        revenue
0 2021-11-01 00:00:00+00:00        300
1 2021-10-01 00:00:00+00:00        500
2 2021-09-01 00:00:00+00:00        100
3 2021-08-01 00:00:00+00:00        50
4 2021-07-01 00:00:00+00:00        200
5 2021-06-01 00:00:00+00:00        150
```

Approximate expected Dataframe with `revenue` divided over the days in that month

```
                                 revenue
date                                    
2021-06-01 00:00:00+00:00    4.8
2021-06-02 00:00:00+00:00    4.8
2021-06-03 00:00:00+00:00    4.8
2021-06-04 00:00:00+00:00    4.8
2021-06-05 00:00:00+00:00    4.8
...                                  ...
2021-11-28 00:00:00+00:00    9.6
2021-11-29 00:00:00+00:00    9.6
2021-11-30 00:00:00+00:00    9.6
2021-11-31 00:00:00+00:00    9.6
```

ie, i want to be sure that the values get divided over the amount of days in that sepcific month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `asfreq` to convert the timeseries from monthly to daily frequency, then use `ffill` to forward fill the values then divide the `revenue` by `daysinmonth` attribute of `datetimeindex` to calculate distributed revenue

```
s = df.set_index('date')
s.loc[s.index.max() + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()] = np.nan

s = s.asfreq('D').ffill()
s['revenue'] /= s.index.daysinmonth
```

---

```
print(s)
                             revenue
date                                
2021-06-01 00:00:00+00:00   5.000000
2021-06-02 00:00:00+00:00   5.000000
2021-06-03 00:00:00+00:00   5.000000
2021-06-04 00:00:00+00:00   5.000000
2021-06-05 00:00:00+00:00   5.000000
...
2021-07-24 00:00:00+00:00   6.451613
2021-07-25 00:00:00+00:00   6.451613
...
2021-11-30 00:00:00+00:00  10.000000
```